# Did Abin Sur not make the prison good enough to hold Parallax forever and how was Abin Sur defeated so easily?

Tags: plot-explanation, green-lantern

According to the movie  [Green Lantern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern_%28film%29#Plot)

> Millions of years ago, a group of beings called the Guardians of the Universe used the green essence of willpower to create an intergalactic police force called the Green Lantern Corps. They split the universe into 3600 sectors, with one Green Lantern per sector. One such Green Lantern, Abin Sur of Sector 2814, defeated the being Parallax and imprisoned him in the Lost Sector on the ruined planet Ryut.

In the movie we see, some alien astronauts crashed on Ryut and inform the base that they have crashed on Ryut and requests for help. During their walking, they fell into a pit and found Parallax. But despite being imprisoned, he took their lives, became strong and broke the prison.

It seems somewhat faulty. Did Abin Sur, the great Lantern, make such a fragile prison to hold an evil such as Parallax, so that it could easily be broken? And did Abin Sur not know that he can eat on lives by his eye? If he knew, why did not he make such a mechanism(like a cover in-front of his eyies or opaque jail), so that Parallax cannot take lives from a distance? Certainly he did not do it intentionally. And also we see, right after his flee from the prison, Parallax attacks Abin Sur and surprisingly, Abin Sur could not return a good fight, which is somehow not expected from him. Let it be taken that, Parallax became stronger feeding upon those astronomers lives. But how come he so easily vanquished Abin Sur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[Green Lantern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern_%28film%29)** movie is only very loosely based on the comic book series. As opposed to being imprisoned in a prison of emerald crystal in the movie, Parallax was originally captured in the [Green Lantern Central Power Battery](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Central_Power_Battery) as the yellow impurity. He then escapes from it to wreak havoc.

However, none of that happens in the movie so we can only speculate. The prison he was in was created by Abin Sur. Seeing as only Abin Sur could stand up against Parallax, he must have been very powerful. His prison would have been even more powerful to hold him. As with all Green Lantern things, it's only as strong as the willpower that drives it. It is possible **the willpower of Abin Sur had diminished since the time he imprisoned Parallax**. While it originally was strong enough to hold a powerfull Parallax, it is now weaker and, apparently, weak enough for Parallax. Parallax's powers also weakened (as he was there for quite some time without anybody around to give him power) during his captivity which is probably why he could only escape when the astronauts were there.

Could Abin Sur have used eye patches? Perhaps, but there might have been better things that were no longer there.

I mentioned that Abin Sur's powers could have diminished since he imprisoned Parallax. This can be found in the comic books as [Abin Sur](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Abin_Sur) had heard of the Blackest Day prophecy. He then started to use a spaceship while all Green Lanterns could easily travel using their power rings. As Abin Sur no longer trusted his resolve and **feared** the prophecy and Parallax had the advantage of catching him offguard, he was able to defeat Abin Sur.

Answer (score 2):

This question depends on which side you want it from, the movie reference or the comic canon?
In the movies it is not really explained but from what I can gather Parallax had been feeding off the organisms fear each time they came in close proximity. Then when the astronauts crashed this was the last bit of fear that he needed to escape, by this time his power had grown to match Abin Sur's which is why he was able to escape. From what I can gather he then went and fed on others fear and became more powerful, so powerful that he was able to defeat Abin Sur. And because his power can grow each time he feeds on fear, and because Abin Sur was not ready, a bit out of practice and his power had maybe diminished a little he was defeated. Although I still think that he was one of the greatest Green Lantern's as he was not scared and still had the Will to fight back a little whereas some of the other's were fed on later on in the film. Abin Sur lived long enough (with a hole in his chest, not many could do this) for the ring to find a new member.